# Mongoose Populate a field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have two mongoose schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var itemSchema = new Schema({

    name: {type: String, required: true, max: 25, trim: true},
    price: {type: Number, required: true, trim: true, default: 0},
    tax: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Store"
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema);
```

The second Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var storeSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
    taxes: [
        {
            name: String,
            rate: Number
        }
    ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Store', storeSchema);
```

What I want to do is populate the itemSchema tax object with the storeSchema taxes array of object. every time I pushed a new tax object to the taxes array mongoose created an ObjectId. I stored that ObjectId in my itemSchema Tax. I want to use that _id to retrieve the store taxes that matches the itemSchema _id.

I have tried this so far, but I get no in the tax attribute.

```
Item.find().populate("tax", "taxes").exec(function (err, docs) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log(items);
    });
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I get null in the tax field.

Comment: Everything else are you getting fine??

Comment: yes im getting everything else.

Comment: i looked at the question once again, i had understood it wrong earlier. You are trying to populate using a sub documents ObjectId, which is not possible. That is why you are getting null.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query

```
Item.find().populate({
    path: 'tax',
    select: 'taxes'
}).exec(function (err, docs) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log(docs);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Item.find().populate(path:"tax", model: )
```

Mention your item model file name... don't use `""` or `''` for the file name, simply add the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Item.find().populate("Store", "taxes")` instead of `Item.find().populate("tax", "taxes")`.